# Adverb placements

Tags: differences, adverbs, adverb-position, emphasis

I came across this sentence and had a hard time understanding it because of the adverb placement. I thought adverbs or adverb phrases usually come right after the verb when "be" is the main verb.

> As with most psychoanalytic theorizing, evidence in support of these views is restricted for the most part to conclusions drawn from Clinical case reports.

So instead of the sentence above, would it sound more natural like this?

> As with most psychoanalytic theorizing, evidence in support of these views is for the most part restricted to conclusions drawn from Clinical case reports.

Or does the sentence above sound natural as well? If it's correct, what is the difference? Is it emphasizing a certain word?

Comment: I read #1 to limit which conclusions, and #2 to limit how restricted.

Comment: Equivalent; both quite formal.

Answer (score 0):

Both word orders are acceptable. If the writer had used *mostly* or *mainly* instead of *for the most part*, they would usually come before *restricted.*

Placing the verb first gives it a little more prominence.

Comment: I agree that both are acceptable but would suggest placing parenthetic commas around **for the most part** in both cases. Do you agree? In one sense the parenthesis removes the OP's problem really.

Comment: Yes, parenthetic commas would make the meaning clearer.